# How to change keyboard type?

Tags: keyboard

There was an option in older versions of Ubuntu to select type of your keyboard — for example PC105, Apple, etc. Now I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Logitech Illuminated Keyboard. The thing is that Winkey here is a Level 3 <kbd>Shift</kbd> and Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is Mod2+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. I want to return correct values for this buttons. Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a keyboard model. Unfortunately I haven't found your “Logitech Illuminated Keyboard” in a list of supported keyboard models. You'll probably need to select different one with compatible layout.

[Release Notes for Debian 6](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#unity-keyboard-settings) (on which Ubuntu is based) says where keyboard model can be found:

> In this new release, the settings for the keyboard have been unified so that both the console and the Xorg server use the same settings. The keyboard settings are now defined in the `/etc/default/keyboard` configuration file which overrides the keyboard defined in Xorg's configuration file.

You can change it:

- either by editing `XKBMODEL` variable in `/etc/default/keyboard`. For available values see contents of the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.lst`.
- or by running

  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

  in a terminal.